# Can I deploy to Firebase without creating realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

I'm trying to make first deploy to firebase from NodeJS project and I haven't set up realtime database because I'm planning on using Firestore only.
However when I run `firebase deploy` from project terminal it throws me this error - `It looks like you haven't created a Realtime Database instance in this project before. Please run firebase init database to create your default Realtime Database instance.` Can I avoid creating Realtime database and still being able to deploy?
Firebase configs used(obviously I ran `yarn build` beforehand):

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "[API_KEY]",
  authDomain: "[AUTH_DOMAIN]",
  projectId: "[PROJECT_ID]",
  messagingSenderId: "[SENDER_ID]",
  appId: "[APP_ID]",
};
```

Comment: Don't know much but you can start looking at this source. 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/firestore
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/friendlyeats-web/

Comment: What have you configured the Firebase CLI to actually deploy?  `firebase deploy` will attempt to deploy everything you have configured.  If you don't want to deploy something, don't configure it.  If you want more help with this, you should share your configuration, or at least the full steps that anyone can follow that got you to where you are now.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry for late reply, I updated the question with configs I have. Btw the code is already functional project that has been copied over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else makes this rookie mistake - be careful not to mistake "database" configuration in firebase.json with "firestore". The "database" configures Realtime Database instead of Firestore

Comment: So to embellish this answer a bit further: Remove the "database" section from firebase.json and delete database.rules.json if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

[From  Github sample sources](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/firestore#setup-and-run-the-app)

```
# after initializing firebase and cli

firebase deploy --only firestore

firebase serve
```